# Reactive API counterpart of javax.sound?

Tags: rx-java, javasound

Over the years it looks like a lot of work was done to create non-blocking alternatives for various kinds of I/O streams in Java.

What is the state of the art for reactive development around `javax.sound`?

Comment: Afaik, there is no non-blocking API for Java Sound. Maybe Virtual Threads work. In any case, the main concern would be is crackling/delays due to non-blocking tasks not resuming fast enough, i.e., latency introduced by reactive/executors.

Comment: @akarnokd I feared it might be something like that. UI development has seemingly gone 100% reactive in recent years, but the Java Sound API has not. And mixing blocking calls into otherwise non-blocking coroutines is apparently an extremely bad idea. Booting it off to a thread might work but I guess I'd have to use an event queue of some sort so that I can still talk to it.